Excel Workbook Errors After Loading Data Validation from VBA
I have a cell ("C10") on an Excel worksheet in which I load a data validation list from an array using the code below. The code creates a dropdown list of Windows files. The code works fine, however, when I reopen the workbook, I get an error prompt that all of the data validations have been cleared on the worksheet, even the cells that have data validation created manually referencing a traditional column range of cells. When I look at the data validation for the cell created by the code it looks fine, though very long. What am I doing wrong?
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
'---> PURPOSE:  Called when a cell is selected.

Dim ws As Worksheet:    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
Dim myCell As Range:    Set myCell = ws.Range("C10")
Dim iSect As Range

Dim sTemplatePath As String
sTemplatePath = '[my valid Windows file path]

Set iSect = Application.Intersect(Target, myCell)

If Not iSect Is Nothing Then

    With myCell.Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:=Join(GetWindowsFiles(sTemplatePath), ",")
    End With
    
End If

End Sub

Function GetWindowsFiles(ByVal sPath As String)
On Error GoTo codeErr
'---> PURPOSE:  Create array with list of files in a Windows folder

Dim vaArray     As Variant
Dim i           As Integer
Dim oFile       As Object
Dim oFSO        As Object
Dim oFolder     As Object
Dim oFiles      As Object

Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set oFolder = oFSO.GetFolder(sPath)
Set oFiles = oFolder.Files

If oFiles.Count = 0 Then Exit Function

ReDim vaArray(1 To oFiles.Count)
i = 1
For Each oFile In oFiles
    vaArray(i) = oFile.Name
    Debug.Print oFile.Name
    i = i + 1
Next

GetWindowsFiles = vaArray

codeExit:
    Exit Function
codeErr:
    Debug.Print Err.Number & " " & Err.Description
    Resume codeExit
End Function


Your validation list assigned to Formula1 can't be longer than 255 characters, or you will have this problem.  If your list is longer than that you will need to store it in a range and reference if from there.

Yes, that works now. Thank you!

You could write the file names to a (very) hidden sheet and 'redirect' the validation to this list. Here's a link to a downloadable file showing how I did it.
